# How to format time and convert to gmt time?

Tags: python, time

I have a date string in the format of 3/29/2010. Can someone tell me how to convert it to GMT time?

Comment: Sorry, but this code is weird and the description extremely poor. Please re-edit your question in a coherent way.

Comment: It's rather hard to see what's going on here, since we lack information about several variables. I suggest you insert `print` statements here and there to check your notion of what values the variables are holding.

Comment: i edited the question based on people told me about date conversion

Comment: Are you having trouble actually reading the documentation for `datetime.strptime`?  http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: @S.Lott:  I didnot really have much time to read it before, nor do i think i would understand because i was trying to solve the prob asap. anyway i'll read it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This very suspiciously appears that you are trying to correct something for daylight savings time, which is not really something you should be doing manually.

You should review the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) documentation, and specifically the portions related to using [time zones](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo).

Comment: yes that's what i'm trying to do. i'm thinking doing it manually because it might take less time than use the time-zone thing(just reviewed it quickly). Since the table is updating some data correctly, it must be just minor problems about the codes (if statement)

Comment: No, you are **wrong** widget. It will take more time and it won't be right. At all.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (timeH,timeM)>(2,0): # if it is after 2 am
    timeH1=timeH+5
    if timeH1>=24:#deduct 24 hrs whenever it's over 24
        timeH1=timeH1-24
else:
    timeH1=timeH+4
```

could be changed to:
        timeH1 = (timeH + 5) % 24

and you also  need to check the other case and subtract 24 which you aren't doing now