# Converting 12 hour format time string (with am/pm) into UTC in 24 hour format

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have time string `11:15am` or `11:15pm`.
I am trying to convert this string into UTC timezone with 24 hour format.

FROM EST to UTC

For example: When I pass `11:15am` It should convert into `15:15` and when I pass `11:15pm` then it should convert to `3:15`.

I have this code which I am trying:

```
def appointment_time_string(time_str):
    import datetime
    a = time_str.split()[0]

    # b =  re.findall(r"[^\W\d_]+|\d+",a)

    # c = str(int(b[0]) + 4) + ":" + b[1]
    # print("c", c)



    in_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(a,'%I:%M%p')

    print("In Time", in_time)

    start_time = str(datetime.datetime.strftime(in_time, "%H:%M:%S"))

    print("Start TIme", start_time)

    if time_str.split()[3] == 'Today,':
        start_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT")
    elif time_str.split()[3] == 'Tomorrow,':
        today = datetime.date.today( )
        start_date = (today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT")

    appointment_time = str(start_date) + str(start_time)

    return appointment_time

x = appointment_time_string(time_str)
print("x", x)
```

But this is just converting to 24 hour not to UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the time from 12 hours to 24 hours format, you may use below code:

```
from datetime import datetime
new_time = datetime.strptime('11:15pm', '%I:%M%p').strftime("%H:%M")
# new_time: '23:15'
```

In order to convert time from `EST` to `UTC`, the most reliable way is to use third party library [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/). Refer [How to convert EST/EDT to GMT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5491705/2063361) for more details

Comment: I got this part, now I need to convert this to uTC timezone

Comment: In which time zone it is currently?

Comment: It is in EST timezone and want to UTC

Comment: Added the link to the solution. OR, you may alternately, subtract the time by 12 hours and  you'll get what you desire

Answer (score 0):

Developed the following script using provided options/solutions to satisfy my requirement.

def appointment_time_string(time_str):

```
    import datetime
    import pytz

    a = time_str.split()[0]

    in_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(a,'%I:%M%p')

    start_time = str(datetime.datetime.strftime(in_time, "%H:%M:%S"))

    if time_str.split()[3] == 'Today,':
        start_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    elif time_str.split()[3] == 'Tomorrow,':
        today = datetime.date.today( )
        start_date = (today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    appointment_time = str(start_date) + " " + str(start_time)

    # print("Provided Time", appointment_time)

    utc=pytz.utc
    eastern=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
    fmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
    # testeddate = '2016-09-14 22:30:00'

    test_date = appointment_time

    dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(test_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    dt_str = datetime.datetime.strftime(dt_obj, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    date=datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    date_eastern=eastern.localize(date,is_dst=None)
    date_utc=date_eastern.astimezone(utc)

    # print("Required Time", date_utc.strftime(fmt))

    return date_utc.strftime(fmt)
```